# I am getting this black screen instead of the app screen on ionic?How to solve this?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am getting this black screen instead of the app screen on ionic?How to solve this?

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfectly working app as you can see a page in Ionic...

Answer (score 0):

That's a black Ionic theme, you need to remove it in ***variables.scss*** file

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
```

...
}